# How does a bound Jtable or Jlist return a database object to be used with a JPAController?

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jtable

a Java and netbeans noob here. I have a Jtable bound to my Javadb. I can interact with the database using a JPAController. I can easily access the object using a JComboBox and the getSelectedItem() method and casting it to my database object in order to edit or destroy. For example:

```
private void deleteInfoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    Customers deleteInfo = (Customers) DeleteInfoComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    if (deleteInfo != null) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomersPU");
        CustomersJpaController cjc = new CustomersJpaController(emf);
        try {
            cjc.destroy(deleteInfo.getId());
        } catch (NonexistentEntityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DeleteInformant.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way to return an object using a Jtable or Jlist? I have tried to use the getSelectedRow() method but this only returns an integer related to the row in the Jtable which is different from the ID in my database. The only other method I see that returns an object is getValueAt(), but it returns the object of the specified cell. For Jlist, getSelectedValuesList() just returns a vector of strings. getSelectedValues() seems to do what I wanted but is depreciated. From other posts ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754752/how-to-insert-update-and-delete-items-from-jtable-that-is-loaded-from-sqlite)), it seems like I may need to make a custom tablemodel but that example didn't seem to take into account having an auto generated JPAController using netbeans.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update: Here is the auto generated code that populates the Jlist with values as requested:

```
 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    CustomersPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomersPU").createEntityManager();
    customerssQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : CustomersPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Customers i");
    customersList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : customersQuery.getResultList();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JListBinding jListBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJListBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, customersList, jList1);
    bindingGroup.addBinding(jListBinding);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(54, 54, 54)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(130, 130, 130)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)))
            .addContainerGap(105, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    bindingGroup.bind();

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: Please, post the code, that populates `JList` with values.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't looked at the auto-generated code that closely. I now see a customersList variable that can be used to access the Customers objects. There may be a more elegant way to do it, but I found a solution that works. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans auto-generates a variable called customersList which contains a list of Customers objects that populates the Jtable or Jlist. This variable can be used to access the selected object(s) by using the get() method with the index of the selected item.

For a Jtable:

```
Customers selectedCustomer = customersList.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
```

For a Jlist with multiple selections, an array of Customers objects can be generated that can be iterated through and manipulated with the JPAController:

```
 Customers[] selectedCustomers = new Customers [jList1.getSelectedIndices().length];

    for (int i = 0; i < jList1.getSelectedIndices().length; i++) {
        selectedCustomers[i] = customersList.get(jList1.getSelectedIndices()[i]);
    }
```

This only works if the order of the Jlist or Jtable do not change. If you want to be able to sort your items, then you can iterate through the list to find the correct object. This is how I implemented this in my Jtable utilizing the ID column of my table:

```
public static int idColumn = 0;

for (Customers i : customersList) {
    if (i.getId() == jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), idColumn)) {
        Customers selectedCustomer = i;
    }
}
```